# Display MongoDB collection data using PUG (Error: Array Undefined)

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, express, pug

I am trying to display the data from my "users" collection in my MongoDB but receiving an undefined error with the array.

In my user controller file, I have imported express, express.router and my user model.

Here is the GET method I am using:

```
router.get('/adminPanel', (req, res) => {
    try{
        const userArr = userModel.getAllUsers();
        res.render('adminPanel', { users: userArr });
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Here is the PUG code I am using to display the rendered data (adminPanel.pug):

```
      table
        thead 
          tr 
            th User ID 
            th Username
            th Admin
        tbody
          if users 
            each user in users
              tr 
                td= user.id 
                td= user.username
                td= user.isAdmin
          else 
            tr 
              td(colspan='3') No users found
```

I have imported the controller and mounted it within my app.js file.

(NodeJS application using MVC architecture)

I've tried modifying my GET method to no avail.

I have ran the following test function within my user controller to debug:

```
function test(){
    const users = userModel.getAllUsers();
    console.log(users);
}

test();
```

This did log the desired data in the console, there is just an issue with rendering it to the PUG file.

My only guess is that my PUG file is loading before the query and therefore reading an undefined array?

**EDIT**

getAllUsers() function defined in user model

```
async function getAllUsers() {
    try {
        const users = await userModel.find().select("_id username isAdmin");
        console.log(users);
        return users;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

**ANSWER**

Marked answer fixed 1 of two errors, I was calling an async function without "await" so it was not waiting for the returned promise.

The other error was within my mount, previously I had:

```
app.use("/user", userController);
```

Which was the incorrect path to the page, fixed by changing to:

```
app.use("/adminPanel", userController);
```

Comment: how getAllUsers look like

Comment: @cmgchess Oh yeah, I'll edit my post and add the code for that function at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that `getAllUsers` is an async function. It seems like you are not awaiting for the `getAllUsers()` function to resolve the promise.

1. You should use `await` when calling it in your route.
2. You should make your route handler is async.

```js
router.get('/adminPanel', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const userArr = await userModel.getAllUsers();
        res.render('adminPanel', { users: userArr });
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I believe that was 1 of 2 errors. The 2nd error I think was in my mount as I believe I was attempting to mount my controller onto the wrong page.